# Jquery click on span IE-11

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-11

I have an HTML that I am trying to click in IE11 and looks like this

```
<span tabindex="0" class="xyz" id="bpm.mnit_Nav" .. >
<span class="123">N</span>
avigate
</span>
```

in the console, I am trying

```
$("[id='bpm.mnit_Nav']").on('click', 'xyz hover', function(){console.log('done');});
```

and it errors in the console

> object doesn't support property or method 'on'

Comment: what is `'xyz hover',`?

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using.

Comment: `xyz hover` is dynamically created class when I hover over the element . How do I fing jquery version in ie11 ?

Comment: if it is class it is missing `.` and why does it have space between it is that `hover` is child of `xyz`?

Comment: that dynamic class is named like this `bi-x-y x-y x-y-hover`  and I tried like `bi-x-y.x-y.x-y-hover` but same result . when I find by id the element is returned `$("[id=bpm.mnit_Nav']")`

Comment: Add that demo on the OP so we can see

Comment: You really should redesign so that you create separate classes, rather than concatenating them like that. To match that you need something like `[class*=hover]`

Comment: This makes no sense to begin with. When you supply a selector like that, it means the _descendant_ elements of the element you are binding this handler to are checked for whether they match that selector. But the span element you are binding this to here does not have any such descendants - it has the class `xyz` itself. // This still lacks a proper explanation of what you actually want to _achieve_ here in the first place IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

Can you style the span as a block element? This helped me previously with a similar IE11 issue.

Answer (score 0):

"Object does not support" error only come up if your jQuery does not have "on" function.
If you have added jquery script in your code, then check it's version. because prior to 1.7, "on" method was not there. in that case, you have to use "bind" method.

Comment: 'bind' gives me the same result. When try to find j query version '$().jquery', '$.fn.jquery' gives error in console

Comment: what error do you get when you run "$.fn.jquery". this should give version of jquery.

Comment: I get `unable to get property 'jquery' of undefined or null reference`

Answer (score 0):

Below is more concise and readable code.

if "hover" is child class of "xyz" :

```
$("#bpm.mnit_Nav").on('click', '.xyz .hover', function(){console.log('done');});
```

if "hover" is same level class of "xyz" :

```
$("#bpm.mnit_Nav").on('click', '.xyz.hover', function(){console.log('done');});
```